# Switched from Sublime to PhpStorm: Magento can't find class anymore

Tags: phpstorm

I get suddenly the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sales_Model_Order' not found in
/projecs/magento/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php on line 562
```

I did not change any files, even reverted with my git to a commit which I already deployed to stage and live and they are working.

The only thing I changed is, that I switched from Sublime to PhpStorm.
But I don't get why it's not working any more, when my git is not showing any changes.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Seemed like the changes of the log file were not shown by the tail command. After reopening them, I found out, that PhpStorm changed the owner to "me:me", but I need "me:www-data"

Comment: What kind of URLs are you using? My thought is -- maybe you were using your Apache (or whatever you have got there) and now you are using PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server .. which may not see all the configs you have had originally (e.g. becaus eit uses different php.ini etc)...

Comment: I didn't configure PhpStorm's built-in web server, so I'm still using my apache. To be sure now, I checked my apache access.log which is changing when I'm accessing my magento via browser

Comment: PhpStorm's one is used by default if you use "Open in Browser" or similar action and have no default deployment entry configured. It will use port number and project name in URL .. so you would easily notice the difference (e.g. `localhost:63342/ProjectName/index.php`). Since your Apache confirms that it serves the files .. then this is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: Maybe some caching issue somewhere (e.g. OpCache .. or composer autoloading (if you are using it)). It may sound stupid.. but have you tried restarting? Becaise fi this is not served by PhpStorm's server .. then I do not see how else it can affect your code (especially if it's the same as already running in production).

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I'm not using "open in browser", I just type the url directly in my browser. I already restarted apache (even stopped, checked that it's not working, and started again) and since I can't use the backend because of this error, I also emptied the var/cache directory. no success :(

Comment: It seems that my "tail -f system.log" command was stuck and not showing me the errors magento was throwing there for me. The problem is, that PhpStorm is chaning permissions when re-saving a file. Suddenly the owner is not anymore me:www-data but me:me. Any idea how to change that? :)

Comment: Try this: `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings --> Use "Safe write"` -- disable it. Now IDE will just overwrite edited file instead of making temp copy first and then replacing original file. This usually solves such problems.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you want to post this as an answer which I will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | System Settings`
2. Disable `Use "Safe write"` option

This will tell IDE to overwrite edited file directly instead of making temp copy first and then replacing original file. This usually solves such "wrong owner/permission" problems.